# Getting "IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'histCSM4r6.nc'" when I try to run the below code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I keep getting IOError: `[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'histCSM4r6.nc'` as output when I run the below code to try to create a NetCDF file.

I have run other codes successfully that involve the same file before, so I'm not sure what's wrong this time. I'm not very experienced.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np

root_grp = Dataset('histCSM4r6.nc', 'w', format='NETCDF4')
root_grp.description = 'Example temperature data'

# dimensions
root_grp.createDimension('time', None)
root_grp.createDimension('lat', 72)
root_grp.createDimension('lon', 144)

# variables
times = root_grp.createVariable('time', 'f8', ('time',))
latitudes = root_grp.createVariable('latitude', 'f4', ('lat',))
longitudes = root_grp.createVariable('longitude', 'f4', ('lon',))
temp = root_grp.createVariable('temp', 'f4', ('time', 'lat', 'lon',))

# data
lats =  np.arange(-90, 90, 2.5)
lons =  np.arange(-180, 180, 2.5)
latitudes[:] = lats
longitudes[:] = lons
for i in range(5):
    temp[i,:,:] = np.random.uniform(size=(len(lats), len(lons)))

# group
# my_grp = root_grp.createGroup('my_group')

root_grp.close()
```

Comment: Obviously, you don't have access to the file you are trying to read. This is not a python problem, but a permission problem on your system. Maybe try `Dataset(... 'r', ...)` instead, you may have read permission but no write permission...

Comment: What have you tried so far?